# Initializing matrix variable in a C struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct transform {
    double A[4][4];
};
```

I *know* I can initialize the entire struct like so:

```
struct transform myTransform;
myTransform = (struct transform){{{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}}};
```

But why can I not do the following?

```
struct transform secondTransform;
secondTransform.A = {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

My logic says that makes sense. I just extend the same logic as before, but only initialize the `A` matrix within my struct, but I receive an ambiguous `Expected expression` error.

The reason I ask is, I have a more complex struct than this in my project and I would like to specifically initialize elements within that struct instead of the whole thing.

Edit: I am using the C99 standard for my project.

Comment: Because that syntax will only work when the variable is defined - even though it might seem logical.

Comment: @WeatherVane But it *is* defined in `struct transform`, is it not?

Comment: `secondTransform.A = ` is not the definition, it is an assignment, and the rules of syntax say "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the first case is an *initialization* while the second case is an *assignment*, and you can't assign to an array.

You can however initialize a struct without explicitly initializing all members.  This is done with a **designated initializer**.

```
struct transform {
    double A[4][4];
    int b;
    char *c;
};

struct transform t = { .A = {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}}, .b = 5 };
```

Any field not explicitly initialized is implicity initialized to 0 or NULL as appropriate for the type.

Comment: Designated initializer. This is exactly what I spent 45 minutes on google looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no fundamental reason why the C compiler couldn't be designed so that it could figure out what you meant there. It just happens to be the case that C only lets you use brace initialization in certain cases, and that isn't one of them.

Comment: So is this a case of 'nobody thought to add this to the C standard'?